# How to stop a zsh script from being suspended (tty output)

Tags: linux, scripting, background, zsh

I have a zsh script that I want to run such that it also loads up my .zshrc file.
I believe I have to run my script in interactive mode?

Thus, my script begins like:

```
#!/bin/zsh -i

if [ $# = 0 ]
then
    echo "need command line paramter..."
    exit
fi
```

However, when I try to run this script in the background, my script becomes suspended (even if I pass in the correct number of parameters):

```
[1]  + suspended (tty output)
```

My question is: How can I make a script that can run in the background that also loads my startup .zshrc file? If I have to put it into interactive mode, how can I avoid the suspension on tty output problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please include the full command you used to start your script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use interactive mode as a hash-bang!

Instead, source your zshrc file in the script if you want it:

```
#!/bin/zsh
source ~/.zshrc
...
```

For future reference, you can use the `disown` bultin to detach a previously backgrounded  job from the shell so it can't be suspended or anything else. The parent shell can then be closed with no affect on the process:

```
$ disown %1
```

You can do this directly from the command line when you start the program by using the `&!` operator instead of just `&`:

```
$ ./my_command &!
```

Comment: Hmm, the `&!` sort of worked in my usecase, but I wanted the background script to also report something back once it's done. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Why this doesn't work from inside an alias?

Comment: @DimiDak One likely reason is you are using Bash not ZSH. A second suggestion would be to use a function, not an alias, if you want to reuse something like this by putting it in your profile.

Comment: @Caleb I'm using zsh. I transferred all my aliases from my .bashrc. I don't want to convert them to functions. So I was wondering why doesn't it work as alias. One thing I noticed is, it works when I use sudo before using this alias. I guess it has something to do with cached credentials. I forgot to mention my alias contains sudo.

Comment: @DimiDak That's on you. You can't **disown** a process and still expect it to be able to connect to your terminal to prompt you for passwords. That's not ZSH and it's not this syntax. Maybe hack it by including `sudo -v; ...` at the start of your alias, but it will still be brittle.